# Error setting text to a textView from strings.xml via java code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview, settext

I just want to set a text in a textView from strings.xml using java code but I just can't, eclipse gives me this error: "textView1 cannot be resolved" and "textView2 cannot be resolved".

Here is mi activity:

```
package com.example.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Descripcion extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.descripcion);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    switch (position){
    case 0:

    ImageView imageView0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView0.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    textView1.setText(this,getString(R.string.case0));
    textView2.setText(this,getString(R.string.case0b));

    break;

    case 1:

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView1.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    textView1.setText(this,getString(R.string.case1));
    textView2.setText(this,getString(R.string.case0b));

    break;  
    }
}
}
```

I've beeing looking for a solution for about 3 hours but I can't fid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You didn't define `TextView`

2) You didn't do `findViewById` to get corresponding `TextView`

**How to do that?**

Your code itself has clues on how to do that, example:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
```

Here you defined `ImageView` and pointed it to `R.id.full_image_view` defined in `layout.xml`

like this you need to get `TextView`, example:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: I've define my TextView but now I have this error:
The method setText(CharSequence, TextView.BufferType) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (activity, String) activity.java /aplicacion/src/com/example/memepedia line 31 Java Problem

Comment: Why this as first parameter? shouldn't it be just setText(getString(R.string.case1))?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just doing my first app for android, in objective-c you have to define labels and buttons in other file, I forgot that in java it's diferent =D

Answer (score 3):

I can't see where you are declaring your TextView's, such as:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just doing my first app for android, in objective-c you have to define labels and buttons in other file, I forgot that in java it's diferent =D

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. I went from PHP to Java, talk about a learning curve :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the variables `textView1` and `textView2`. Besides that you need to obtain a reference to them using `findViewById`. Weird part is that you did this for `imageView1` and forgot to do it for the `TextViews`.

Add the following piece of code below `etContentView(R.layout.descripcion)`:

`TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(<<-- the id of textView1 -->>);
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(<<-- the id of textView2 -->>);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just doing my first app for android, in objective-c you have to define labels and buttons in other file, I forgot that in java it's diferent =D

Answer (score 0):

That's because textView1 and textView2 aren't defined....

You see what you do with the ImageView?

`ImageView imageView0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);`

You have to apply the same concept to the text views.

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_text_view_1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_text_view_2);
```

Then you can perform operations on that text view, such as setting the text!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just doing my first app for android, in objective-c you have to define labels and buttons in other file, I forgot that in java it's diferent =D

Answer (score 0):

define your textviews as you did your imageview.

you can use

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

where

```
R.id.textView1
```

is the id of your textview1 in your xml layout

```
R.id.textVie2
```

is the id of your textview2 in your xml layout

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just doing my first app for android, in objective-c you have to define labels and buttons in other file, I forgot that in java it's diferent =D